# Keep only unique (first instance of duplicate considered as unique) and drop all other rows in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to figure out a way to sort and keep only unique rows based on column '**Campaign_Query**'(drop duplicates, keeping only the first instance). Say I have 15k rows data daily and it contains 2-3k duplicate values.

**Note**: *I have to identify and drop values based **only** on **'Campaign_Query'***, it doesn't matter if other columns values does not match.

Here's the sample of the data:

| DATE | Site | Label | Campaign_Name | Campaign_Query | COST | REVENUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-31 | receptix.uk | XYZ-Receptixuk-Global | performance-management-platforms | mental health care providers | 15.50 | 103.74 |
| 2022-07-31 | jnee.us | XYZ-Jneeus-Global | healthcare practice jobs | online mental healthcare practice | 15.05 | 41.22 |
| 2022-07-31 | jnee.us | XYZ-Jneeus-Global | care-providers-openings-united-states | mental health care providers | 148.62 | 401.21 |
| 2022-07-31 | jnee.us | XYZ-Jneeus-Global | healthcare practice jobs opportunities | best mental healthcare practice | 146.15 | 329.02 |
| 2022-07-31 | jnee.us | XYZ-Jneeus-Global | computing cloud network monitoring system openings | computing cloud network monitoring system | 140.81 | 234.46 |
| 2022-07-31 | jnee.com | XYZ-Jneecom-Global | health-counselor-united-states | mental health counselor openings | 140.24 | 350.33 |
| 2022-07-31 | jnee.us | XYZ-Jneeus-Global | medical staffing solutions employment | medical staffing solutions | 136.08 | 300.67 |
| 2022-07-31 | jnee.com | XYZ-Jneecom-Global | simple-project-management-solution-openings-united-states | digital simple project management solution | 135.98 | 247.78 |
| 2022-07-31 | receptix.us | XYZ-Receptixus-Global | management-solutions-employments #701 | medical inventory management solutions | 132.93 | 281.35 |
| 2022-07-31 | jnee.us | XYZ-Jneeus-Global | healthcare practice psychiatric jobs opportunities | medical staffing solutions | 132.44 | 275.17 |

Comment: Did you try `DataFrame.drop_duplicates` with the `keep` parameter set to 'first' and `subset` set to your column name, `Campaign_Query`?

Comment: df.groupby('Campaign_Query').head(1)   Does this work for you?

Comment: So both of these work for me, and the result is exactly the same.